# Best way to show multiple images in quick succession

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I'm trying to use `pygame` to flash multiple images in quick succession, but the below code shows a white screen for some time, before showing a single image for a split second, and then closes.

Where am I going wrong?

```
import glob
import pygame
import os
import pathlib
import time

max_idx = 276
imgs_dir = 'path/to/imgs/...'

pygame.init()
w = 480
h = 480
size=(w,h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 
c = pygame.time.Clock()

idx = 0
while idx < max_idx:
    idx+=1
    print(idx)

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    img_path = f'{imgs_dir}/{idx}.png'
    img = pygame.image.load(img_path)
    img_rect = img.get_rect()
    
    screen.blit(img, img_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    
    c.tick(1000)
```

In my case, the filenames are the indexes, and they exist. (e.g. `'path/to/imgs/0.png'`, ..., `'path/to/imgs/275.png'`)

**Updated attempt**

With the feedback, I've updated it to this, but it hasn't resolved the issue:

```
pygame.init()
w = 300
h = 300
size=(w,h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 
c = pygame.time.Clock()

images = []
for idx in range(0, max_idx):
    img_path = f'{new_folder_path}/{idx}.png'
    img = pygame.image.load(img_path)
    img = pygame.transform.scale(img, size)
    images.append(img)

for img in images:  # I want it to close as soon as all images have been shown
    img_rect = img.get_rect()
    screen.blit(img, img_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    c.tick(0.5)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The code looks right. Are you sure that the image files actually have stuff in them and that the images in them are the size you want to display?

Comment: Hi Glenn, the images definitely exist (and have contents), and the sizes of the images match the set size of the screen.

Comment: I missed the framerate you are using as @kaktus_car mentions below, A frame rate of 1000 will mean it will try to do 1000 frames per second, so it will whip through all 276 images in about 1/4 of a second if it can go that fast. That is likely part of your issue. Since all you are doing is displaying these then you want a frame rate that lasts as long as you want it displayed. In your case you likely want more than a second per frame. Try `c.tick(0.5)`. I believe you can use frame rates that cause >1 second frame intervals, though I have never tried it.

Comment: Hi Glenn, my bad! @kaktus_car also pointed this out, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. It still stays blank (though now for longer) until the last image which will flash once and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading images outside the `main_loop` since loading takes some time. Also the program will exit when the `idx` become `True` and that in your case is after 276 iterations, now your frame rate is set to 1000, reduce your number of frames.
If you want to prevent program from exiting remove `idx` from the `while` condition and put some other variable which will become `True` when you close the window (and optionally add some other triggers) i.e. :

```
run = True
...
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
```

Also put `pygame.quit()` at the end.

EDIT: Solution code

```
import pygame as pg
import os 

WIN_W = 500
WIN_H = 500
FPS = 2

clock = pg.time.Clock()

window = pg.display.set_mode((WIN_W, WIN_H))

images_list = []

def load_images(images_list):
    curr_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    dir_images = os.path.join(curr_dir, "images")

    for i in range(2, 11, 2):   
        images_list.append(pg.image.load(os.path.join(dir_images, f"{i}c.png")))


load_images(images_list)


def redraw(i):

    window.blit(images_list[i], (0,0))

    pg.display.update()


run = True
while run:

    clock.tick(1)

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

    for i in range(len(images_list)):
        pg.time.wait(100)
        redraw(i)

pg.quit()
```

I got the desired result with `pygame.time.wait()`. I'm not 100% sure but I think the problem with our earlier tries was that no matter the FPS the whole code in `for loop` gets executed at once, hence we see only last image. Using this approach only ONE blitting happens each pass. I know you want your program to exit when displaying is finished but this is easier for testing.

NOTE: don't forget to change image paths and variable names.

Comment: Hi @kaktus_car, thanks for this. I've updated with your suggestions, but it's still not working as expected. Any thoughts? I'm happy to let the program exit on completion, hence why I didn't include the latter suggested code fragment.

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. I think you do not need to `transform` images each time, they should be resized, but check this. Could you explain what is happening now, I saw you removed `.fill(255,255,255)` which would display white screen each loop.

Comment: Thanks, I tested with and without the `transform`, and it suggests that it is required to resize the image. The `fill` seemed to have no effect, even after taking it out; the screen pops up, waits and shows nothing until the last image flashes for a split second, then it closes.

Comment: Oh, ok. Just to be clear you want the images to each(of 276) be displayed for example half of a second on the screen and then to finish the program after last one is shown. I want to try it myself, I will get back with the results.

Comment: That's correct - many thanks! I'll watch this space :)